# How do I set the UITableViewCell DetailText Color in iOS 7 using Appearance?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, ios7, appearance

In a `Value1` style `UITableViewCell` the DetailText is gray, I'd like it to be black.  How can I control the color via the appearance proxy?

Thank you.

Comment: The UITableViewCell doesn't support the appearance proxy.. You could subclass it yourself and add the required methods but I have no knowledge on how to do that in monotouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do this ?:

```cs
DetailTextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
```

Comment: Yes but I would have to do it in a lot of places, was hoping for a better way to change detail text color in iOS 7 to make it more readable across the entire app.  Thx

Comment: Doesn't look possible. Sorry.